# Dockerfile from scratch using dynamic build

Tags: docker, g++, dockerfile, data-distribution-service

**The following post it too long , please be patient while going through**

Hi , i'm quite new to docker and dds .

i am creating a simple code using rti-dds and docker .
The code will provide me two exes one for publishing the data and other for subscribing the data.

I want to use FROM scratch in my Dockerfile as i don't need bash nor any os.

Now if i use  FROM scratch do i need to have my exes statically build with the g++ -static flag or can it be done dynamically , that is without the static flag.

**Which one is preferred or is there a rule to it?**

**Docker Verion**

Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.2
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.8
 Git commit:        6a30dfc
 Built:             Thu Aug 29 05:29:11 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

**Dockerfile when exe files are build with -static flag**

```
FROM scratch

COPY rti_license.dat /
COPY USER_QOS_PROFILES.xml /
COPY /objs/x64Linux3gcc4.8.2/DynamicTest_publisher /
COPY /objs/x64Linux3gcc4.8.2/DynamicTest_subscriber /

CMD ["/DynamicTest_publisher"]
```

**The docker image gets successfully build and runs without any error**

**BUT**

**Dockerfile when exe files are build dynamically (without static flag)**

figuring all the dependencies were to be copied as well
checked the dependencies using

ldd on the exe

```
FROM scratch

COPY rti_license.dat /
COPY USER_QOS_PROFILES.xml /
COPY /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 /
COPY /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 /
COPY /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 /
COPY /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 /
COPY /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 /
COPY /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /
COPY /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 /
COPY /objs/x64Linux3gcc4.8.2/DynamicTest_publisher /
COPY /objs/x64Linux3gcc4.8.2/DynamicTest_subscriber /
COPY /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /

CMD ["/DynamicTest_publisher"]
```

**Build the docker image**

```
docker build --tag dynamictest .
```

**But when i try to run this i get the following error**

```
docker run --rm -it dynamictest
```

**Error**
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory

**So , am i missing something here or is it that "FROM scratch only works with static builds"**

Comment: In theory what you're trying to do is possible.  Remember that you can only `COPY` files from within the current directory (`/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` is interpreted relative to the `docker build` directory).  You might try `/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --list /DynamicTest_publisher` as the container command, as a long manual form of `ldd`, and see if it finds everything.

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze , thanks for looking into it , i tried changing the Dockerfile CMD to CMD /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --list /DynamicTest_publisher , still no luck.  `docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --list /DynamicTest_publisher\": stat /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --list /DynamicTest_publisher: no such file or directory": unknown.`

Comment: Why aren't you copying all ndds libraries in a dynamic build?

Comment: @JohnnyWillemsen I did copy all the required libraries , the catch was since i was using scratch i had to ldd on the exe to see what all dynamic libraries were required , and i copied them along with the folder structure, after that i had to copy them in the container too using COPY command in docker file and finally it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**THIS WORKED OUT BEST FOR ME - Dynamic Build**

***The very first thing was to find out all the dependencies for your exe file***

```
    $ldd dytest_publisher

    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffec3df9000)
    libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ffb0e740000)
    libnsl.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007ffb0e526000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ffb0e30a000)
    librt.so.1 => /usr/lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007ffb0e102000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ffb0dd28000)
    libm.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007ffb0da26000)
    libc.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007ffb0d665000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ffb0e945000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/local/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ffb0d44c000)
```

***Copy the above libraries along with the folder structure in your project folder and create a docker file with name Dockerfile***

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM scratch

COPY rti_license.dat / 
COPY USER_QOS_PROFILES.xml /     
COPY /objs/x64Linux3gcc4.8.2/DynamicTest_publisher /     
COPY /objs/x64Linux3gcc4.8.2/DynamicTest_subscriber /     
COPY /lib64/* /lib64/     
COPY /usr/lib64/* /usr/lib64/      

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64/:/lib64/     

CMD ["/dytest_publisher"]
```

*Note: project folder must have the directory: /usr/lib64/ and /lib64/ along with all  the depended libraries. Depended libraries can be checked by the following command :*

```
$ldd "your exe file"
```

**Build the docker image**

```
docker build --tag dynamictest .
```

**Running the created image**

```
docker run --rm -it dynamictest
```

**To see the running container**

```
docker container ls
```

**PS : thanks to everyone for their help on this**

Comment: Made my day! Thank you very much!

Comment: The LD_LIBRARY_PATH line gives a hint that you might not need the complicated structure.

Comment: For someone coming here -- this is not enough, e.g. you need nsswitch and a couple of other files for DNS to work. Then you'll want locale, local users and so on. Some of these extras can be produced by stracing openat and execve syscalls, but not all.